# popup message shown while form closing

Tags: vba, ms-access, module, ms-office, ms-access-2016

I have a database with the following

- Mainfrm Form (Main Form - it has popup messages on load event)
- kikThemOut Form (Loads hidden with Main Form and every 5 sec it checks for field value on table if it is 1 then call the Function fGetOut())
- GetOutMod Module (has fGetOut() Function)

it works all fine, except when application closing it loads the popup alerts from Mainfrm again! which should not load.

**Mainfrm Form Code**

```html
Private Sub Form_Load()


     'to check for T&I notifications
Dim trs As Recordset
    Set trs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Y22_CurrMonth")
    
    If trs.EOF = False Then
        Dim tMsg, tStyle, tTitle, tHelp, tCtxt, tResponse, tMyString
        
tMsg = "There are Notifications Due, Do you want to view them?"
tStyle = vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbDefaultButton2
tTitle = "Notifications Alert"
tHelp = "DEMO.HLP"
tCtxt = 1000
tResponse = MsgBox(tMsg, tStyle, tTitle, tHelp, tCtxt)
If tResponse = vbYes Then    ' User chose Yes.
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Notifications Current Month", acViewReport, acWindowNormal

Else
tMyString = "No"
End If
End If

'to load the checker form
DoCmd.OpenForm "kikThemOut", , , , , acHidden

End Sub
```

and this is the GetOutMod Module to force users to exit the db
**GetOutMod Module**

```html
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function fGetOut() As Integer
Dim RetVal As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As Recordset
On Error GoTo Err_fGGO
Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("KickEmOff", dbOpenSnapshot)
If rst.EOF And rst.BOF Then
 RetVal = True
 GoTo Exit_fGGO
Else
 If DSum("GetOut", "KickEmOff") = "1" Then
      Application.Quit
 Else
  RetVal = True
 End If
End If
Exit_fGGO:
 fGetOut = RetVal
 Exit Function
Err_fGGO:
 'Note lack of message box on error
 Resume Next
End Function
```

And this code in the load event of kikThemOut form to check for the same condition, if it is 1 then load this popup message (I could not add popup message to my GetOutMod Module with the function fGetOut)

**kikThemOut form Code**

```html
Private Sub Form_Timer()
If DSum("GetOut", "KickEmOff") = "1" Then
     Set TaskDialogAC = New cTaskDialog
    With TaskDialogAC
        .Init
        .MainInstruction = "Dashboard Maintenance"
        .Flags = TDF_CALLBACK_TIMER
        .Content = "The Dashboard will be closed after 20 seconds for maintenance"
        .CommonButtons = TDCBF_CLOSE_BUTTON
        .IconMain = IDI_WINLOGO
        .Footer = "Closing in 20 seconds..."
        .Title = "Dashboard Maintenance"
        .AutocloseTime = 20    'seconds
        .ParenthWnd = Me.hwnd
        .ShowDialog
    End With
    Call fGetOut
    Else
If DSum("GetOut", "KickEmOff") = "0" Then
DoCmd.Requery
   
  End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the fGetOut function called? Have you step-debugged?

Comment: You have `Me.Form.Requery` in your `Form_Load` event. That may be causing a another event to run - like @June7 asks - where is your function called from - what event - and what form(s)

Comment: @June7 it's called when the form kikThemOut loads and check for value if valid it will be called

Comment: @dbmitch So, I have Mainform loads and with the Mainform kikThemOut form loads too and check for the if condition if it is valid it will call the fGetOut function to close the db, in kikThemOut form load event I have if condition if it is valid it will show the popup message and counts down to close the db

Comment: You can add global variable `ClosingDB`; set it to `True` in the `fGetOut` function and check to see if it's false along with any other if conditions before you call it

Comment: @dbmitch didn't get you?

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to read your code and figure out where your function is being called from.

But I'm assuming this  should work for you as described

Add this before your `fGetOut` function

```
Public blClosing as Boolean
```

And then add this inside your function at the top (after `On Error GoTo Err_fGGO`)

```
if blClosing then 
    blClosing = False 
    Exit function
Else
    blClosing = True
End if
```

Comment: only one pupup message is gone, I have edited the question to be more clear

Comment: @user2947398 -  Still not clear - What is the message from popup you're seeing? Is it the `There are Notifications Due` popup? Or `Dashboard will be closed` message? or something else